# SQL query to return results with sub list for each item

Tags: sql

This may be a trivial question but I am not finding an answer to it in my searches so any help and or pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated. I think my google skills may just not be asking this correctly. I am trying to return a result set within a result set using a single query.

To make this simple lets assume I have 2 tables.

**Employee table**

```
(employeeID, Name)
```

**Item table**

```
(itemID, employeeId, ItemName)
```

The item table may hold multiple items for each employee.

I can run queries on this all day and get what I want every time but how I want it is the question. The way I would like the data returned would be something like

```
- employee 1
    * Item 1
    * Item 2
    * Item 3
- Employee 2
    * Item 6
    * Item 9
    * Item 10
- Employee 3
    * Item 12
    * Item 14
```

instead of returning a single line for each item. Basically a query with a sub query however I cannot seem to find how to get the returned format I am looking for.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: This seem more like a problem for the UI layer.  Anyway Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Juan Carlos Oropeza answered the question for me below. UNION was the key I was missing. To Answer these replies, I am using SQL Server 2008 and yes this is a UI piece I can work out easily to format the data, I knew I could get the results like I wanted right in the query but for the life of me could not remember how to do it and it turned into more of a curiousity.

Comment: If that solve your problem, remember accept the answer with the green tick

Answer (score 0):

First query give you the list of employee names, and second the list of items for each employee. So you order by employeeID to group everything together. And adding a field title_order so the employee name appear first.

```
 SELECT 'A' as title_order, 
        employeeID,
        Name
 FROM employee

 UNION 
 SELECT 'B' as title_order
        employeeID,
        ItemName as Name
 FROM items

 ORDER BY employeeID, title_order
```

Comment: This gives a great starting point, thank you. Union is the key I was missing